# JSP and derby database class

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, derby

I have a jsp page where I want to place some information from database. 
It's code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Lab4</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='chekboxOfCompanies'>
<%
ArrayList<String> companiesList=DBHandler.getCompaniesList();
for (int i=0;i<companiesList.size();i++){
    out.println("<input type='checkbox'>");
}
%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

DBHandler gets arrayList of names of companies in database. Here it's code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DBHandler {
    public static ArrayList<String> getCompaniesList(){
        Connection conn = null;
        ArrayList<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<Statement>(); 
        Statement s = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String dbName = "Lab4DB";
        ArrayList<String> returnArray=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName);
            System.out.println("Connected to database " + dbName);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            s = conn.createStatement();
            statements.add(s);
            rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT company from companies");
            while(rs.next()){
                returnArray.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
    private static String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
}
```

When I try to run it on server it says that DBHandler cannot be resolved. How can I get this information? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you imported `java.util.ArrayList` to be able to use it, you have to import the `DBHandler` class to be able to use it. If DBHandler is in the default package as it seems to be, then move it in a package. You should never have any class in the default package.

That said, you should also never use scriptlets in JSPs. The DB access code should be called from a Servlet, written in Java, and the servlet should store the list in a request attribute and forward to the JSP. The JSP should use the JSP EL and the JSTL to display this list, and shouldn't contain any Java code.

Comment: Ok, DBHandler class is in the DB package. 
How should I import it? import="DB.DBHandler"?

Comment: import="java.util.ArrayList, DB.DBHandler". Googling for "JSP imports" would have given you the answer. And package names should be in lowercase.